# git: clone from public github to private github

Tags: git, github, version-control

**(dupe note)** Not related to [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations); I don't need multiple locations, just to interact between an internal and public github. **(end note)**

I'm looking for a workflow:

- clone a repo from github.com to an internal github server (not a private repo on github.com)
- make changes and test using internal github server
- potentially pull changes from external github to our internal github
- review changes, send pull request to original github repo

What git incantations will perform these three interactions?

- clone from public to internal github
- pull changes from public to internal github
- push changes from internal to public github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull/push from multiple remote locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your management between the the two Git servers will be managing separate `remote`s between them.

If you are explicit with your `push`'s and `pull`'s you can define a workflow that should be pretty sane.

> clone from public to internal github

```
# this will be a one-time setup

# first clone the public repo
cd /dir/where/you/want/your/repo
git clone <public github url> myRepo
cd myRepo

# create a remote to your internal Git server
git remote add internal <internal repo url>

# push to your internal repo
# (assuming you are working on the master branch)
git push internal master

# now you have effectively "cloned" the public repo
# to your internal server
```

> pull changes from public to internal github

```
# assuming you are on master branch
# and _not_ taking tracking branches
# into account (since IMO they complicate matters)
git checkout master

# pull from github
git pull origin master

# push to internal
git push internal master
```

> push changes from internal to public github

```
git checkout master
git pull internal master
git push origin master
```